# Tire peeling on tread after curbed lightly

Tags: tires

[image]

Hello,

I recently had a nightmare situation where I was stuck between two parked cars. While getting out I lightly curbed the rear tire and the attached image shows the damage. There doesn't seem to be any damage to the important parts of the tire but I'm just checking.

Comment: This looks more like rubber left after the tire was formed, not damage due to running it up on the curb. My opinion is, you shouldn't worry about it, but that's only an opinion.

Comment: I'm with @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2.

Comment: Take a picture from a little further back?

Comment: And to explore Paulster2's theory, look at your other tires for something similar.

Comment: The other tires are similar albeit this one has three of those flaps. I guess I am wondering if this is damage, it doesn't seem major - i.e. it's not deep or on the side wall

Comment: Do you have a pic a bit further back as well?

Answer (score 3):

When a tyre is manufactured it's placed in a mold which is made up of a number of pieces.  The bits of rubber that are forced into the spaces between each section of the mold form these flaps.  This is not tyre damage, it's residual excess rubber left over from the manufacturing process.  It will eventually wear and drop off or can be pulled off (simply by hand) with no adverse effects.

This image shows the tyre mold and you can see each segment.

[image: segmented tyre mold]

Answer (score 1):

If this is actual damage, it is minor. I've had worse. One time, the wife made a right turn way too tight (well, actually, she did that way the heck more than one time), the right rear rode over the curb. Problem: there's a sewer grate on the edge of that curb, kinda like the one pictured below.
[image: Curb sewer on corner]

The concrete was chipped a lot, so she hit the metal edge with the side of the tire while climbing the curb. This made a peeling cut on the sidewall, way worse that what your picture is showing. I went to a tire shop and they said it's nothing, just use rubber contact sement to keep the flap shut.